# PostgreSQL - Loop through alternative query results

Tags: postgresql, loops

On PostgreSQL, I am trying to loop through alternative query results.

I have this solution working:

```
FOR target
IN query
LOOP
  statements
END LOOP;
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
FOR target
IN (IF condition_1
    THEN query_1
    ELSE query_2
    END IF)
LOOP
  statements
END LOOP;
```

However I cannot make it to work. I have also tried this version but it's also not working:

```
FOR target
IN (CASE
      WHEN condition_1 THEN query_1
      ELSE query_2
    END)
LOOP
  statements
END LOOP;
```

Is there any way of implementing this behavior in PostgreSQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
FOR target
IN (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE     condition1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE NOT condition1)
LOOP
  statements
END LOOP;
```

Queries: query1 and query2 are combined with `UNION ALL` but condition will pass only single part depending of value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Lukasz, I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I could make it to work. Once again thank you so much Lukasz!

Comment: @InêsSantos Glad to hear that. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I'm sorry @Luckasz, it was my first question here and I didn't know about accepting answers. I have accepted it now :)